# Introspecting a struct definition with boost.hana

Tags: c++, c++14, boost-hana

Migrating from MPL and Fusion to Hana here!

So assume we have the usual

```
struct Person {
  BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Person,
    (std::string, name),
    (int, age)
  );
};
```

The documentation gives an example of introspecting an *object* of this struct, along the lines of

```
Person john;
static_assert(hana::keys(john) == hana::make_tuple("name"_s, "age"_s));
```

But is it possible to introspect the struct itself, namely, getting the list of fields and their types and names?

Of course, I could impose an additional requirement on the types I'm working with to be default-constructible and just create a dummy object to introspect, but that just seems wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of default construction, you can use [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval). Its use must be inside a `decltype`.

Tentatively, c++20 will support the use of lambdas within `decltype`.

Here is an example that works with c++14.

```cpp
#define BOOST_HANA_CONFIG_ENABLE_STRING_UDL
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <string>

namespace hana = boost::hana;
using namespace hana::literals;

struct Person {
  BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Person,
    (std::string, name),
    (int, age)
  );
};

template <typename S>
constexpr auto names = decltype(hana::unpack(std::declval<S>(),
      hana::on(hana::make_tuple, hana::first))){};

template <typename S>
constexpr auto types = decltype(hana::unpack(std::declval<S>(),
      hana::on(hana::make_tuple, hana::compose(hana::typeid_, hana::second)))){};

int main() {
  static_assert(names<Person> == hana::make_tuple("name"_s, "age"_s), "");
  static_assert(types<Person> == hana::tuple_t<std::string, int>, "");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this great example, I think this is really usefull and might be a good addition to the Boost.Hana user doc, Introspection section -might need step by step explanation though.